# trouble getting the right solution sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to give the DDT like an ID when the DDT is "000A" then the new column = 100
and when the DDT is "000B" then the new column = 200
but the problem is I have like 1000 different DDT rows
I have a table like this

| sy3 | DDT | EXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 000A | 35 |
| 15 | 000B | 40 |
| 16 | 000A | 12 |
| 11 | 000A | 30 |

and I would like it to come out like this:

| sy3 | DDT | EXT | DDT_EXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 000A | 35 | 100 |
| 15 | 000B | 40 | 200 |
| 16 | 000A | 12 | 100 |
| 11 | 000A | 30 | 100 |

Comment: sql server 2005???? Why?

Comment: i can't figure it out

Comment: you have to map your ddt / ddt_ext at some point so you might want to create a table with this map and then join it

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT sy3, DDT, EXT, CASE DDT WHEN '000A' THEN 100 WHEN '000B' THEN 200 END AS DDT_EXT
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that you may also wish at some point to have a formal table which can map from `DDT` values to `DDT_EXT` values, something like this:

```
DDT  | DDT_EXT
000A | 100
000B | 200
```

Comment: but i have not only '000A' and '000B'

Comment: @AzougarMohamed Then either create a separate table with all possible `DDT` values and their extensions and join to it, or expand my `CASE` expression to include all possible values.

Comment: I have more than 1M record in my table

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping table and use that mapping table in the JOIN as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(y3 int, DDT    char(4), EXT int)
DECLARE @tableExtMapping table (DDT char(4), DDT_EXT int)
insert into @table 
values
(12 ,'000A',    35)
,(15    ,'000B',    40)
,(16    ,'000A',    12)
,(11    ,'000A',    30)

insert into @tableExtMapping
values ('000A',100),('000B',200);

SELECT      t.*, e.DDT_EXT
FROM        @table as t
INNER JOIN  @tableExtMapping as e
ON          e.DDT = t.DDT
```

| y3 | DDT | EXT | DDT_EXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 000A | 35 | 100 |
| 15 | 000B | 40 | 200 |
| 16 | 000A | 12 | 100 |
| 11 | 000A | 30 | 100 |